# How do I extract location from Windows using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, geolocation, location, ip-geolocation

Google Maps seems to be able to do this quite well, presumably leveraging my ISP.  How is this done?  Is it possible to tap Google Maps or some other database to derive where the user is?  (Within maybe 1 km?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done through using a GEOIP database.

A company named [Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com) is in this business. There are paid databases and free databases (the latter less accurate, of course).

However, I believe free databases could not be used for your "1km accuracy".

Comment: and @tofutim The GEOIP database (at least the free version) doesn't have the resolution you are looking for.  It will snap, I believe, to the nearest provider address for your ISP.  In my case that's over 60km away.  The only way to get true GPS data is to use a sensor via a device.

Comment: The paid GEOIP database seems quite accurate.

Comment: That's great news, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several webservices that offer IP to Geolocation resolution, even some which are free. [This article: 3 Free Ways to Geolocate By IP](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/03/31/3-free-ways-to-geolocate-by-ip/) should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to first get the User's IP address and then use some API to perform a lookup. Check out:

[C# - Get User Location by IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327629/get-user-location-by-ip-address)