# IP to world region

Tags: web, ip

Is there an easy way to detect user region using IP address? I'd assume that each region will have a specific IPv4 range assigned.

- I don't want to rely on any 3rd party service (except initial data import)
- Precision does not need to be 100%, but should be reasonably high (at least ~80%)
- I only want to guess users region (Europe, Asia, Africa, ...). No need for city/country.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get user location by IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327629/get-user-location-by-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you're using. But you can do it with GeoIP or similar modules. If you dont want any 3rd party libraries at all you can make a function based on IANA numbers [https://www.iana.org/number](https://www.iana.org/numbers). Especially look under "IPv4 Address Space".