# .NET 5 Rest Api get client ip, machine name and location

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular, rest

I have an application in the following configuration:
Frontend -> Angular
Backend -> .Net 5 Web API Hosted in Azure

For security reasons I needed to save the machine name, ip and user's location (city, country) in a table when he logged in.
However as I use API Rest I was not able to find out how to capture this information.

I imagine that the location (city, country) I can get by IP.
But now I'm not able to find a way to find out the user's hostname and ip when he requests the Rest API for Login (Post request).

Comment: Put at least some code that you have tried this.

Comment: Check this link [Get client IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532806/asp-net-web-api-2-1-get-client-ip-address) Then you can also check [Get user location by IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327629/get-user-location-by-ip-address)